# One ViewModel Instance for Multiple Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewmodel

I have 1 activity which contains parent fragment. Inside the parent fragment is 2 child fragments. I want to only create one viewmodel instance and use it in both child fragment.

This is my code in parent fragment:

```
val factory = ViewModelFactory.getInstance(requireContext())
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory)[FavoriteViewModel::class.java]
```

And this one in child fragment:

```
viewModel = (requireParentFragment() as FavoriteParentFragment).viewModel // force close
```

It force close without error in logcat.

When i try to move the parent fragment's code to the activity (without changing the code) and change the child fragment's code to:

```
viewModel = (activity as MainActivity).viewModel // works
```

It works.

So is it possible to do the first method (that is force closed)? If so, how to do that properly and why i did not get any logcat error.

Comment: can try after commenting this line? to make sure that is causing the crash

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to access the viewmodel from the parent directly, use the scope of the parent to get a shared viewmodel.

Inside your child fragments, use this code

```
val factory = ViewModelFactory.getInstance(requireContext())
val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireParentFragment(), factory).get(FavoriteViewModel::class.java)
```

Using the above code, you no longer need to store an instance of the viewmodel in the parent fragment.

Comment: So i don't need to declare anything in parent fragment and just use that on both child because the scope given is ParentFragment?

Comment: Correct. If you want, you can keep the factory in the parent and access it from the children. No need to store the viewmodel in the parent fragment as scope will take care of it

Comment: Are you getting different instances or is the code crashing like before?